# Do While Looping in vb6

Tags: vb6

Can anyone please help me with a Do while Not loop.
I'm very new to programming:

I need to check and print a list, and limit it to 5 names.

```
Do While Not rsP.EOF And iCount > 5
sLT = sLT & rsP![Name] & vbNewLine
iCount = iCount + 1
rsP.MoveNext
Loop

If rsP.RecordCount > 5 Then
sLT = sLT & "..."
End If
```

right now it will not print the list, if I take out iCount > 5, it shows, but I need to limit it to only 5 names maximum to show? What should I change the iCount to?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `iCount` is zero outside the loop:  `iCount > 5` is initially false so the loop does not run.

Simply change to:

```
Do While Not rsP.EOF And iCount < 5
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but even though when I have less than 5 records it still prints/show five records.

Comment: How can it print 5 records if you have less than 5 records?

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the use of negative logic:

```
Do Until rsP.EOF Or iCount >= 5
    sLT = sLT & rsP![Name] & vbNewLine
    iCount = iCount + 1
    rsP.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks again, if I use your code above, it gives me Error: Number 3021

Comment: Error: Dource ADODB.Filed. Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Rejection....

Comment: Works fine here.  Do you set `iCount = 0` and call `rsP.MoveFirst` before the loop?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is trying to evaluate both the recordset EOF and the loop count in the same statement. Try looping the recordset and just exit the loop when the desired number of records has been printed. If you have fewer than 5 records the Do While statement will evaluate to False and that will exit the loop.

```
Do While Not rsP.EOF
    sLT = sLT & rsP![Name] & vbNewLine
    iCount = iCount + 1
    If iCount >= 5 Then
        Exit Do
    End If
    rsP.MoveNext
Loop
```